# Entries in Datasheet view are not reflecting back in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am using SharePoint 2010. Any new entries in Datasheet view are not reflecting back both in standard view and datasheet view. But if the new entries are added through standard view, it is reflecting back both in standard view as well as datasheet view. What's going on there? Can somebody help me?

Comment: If you create a new custom list with only the title field does it suffer from the same affliction?

Comment: No it doesn't. Multiple users can add their data in my list but only one user is facing this strange issue.

Comment: It could be a problem with their browser. I believe datasheet view in 2010 uses an ActiveX plugin.

Comment: I don't think it will be a problem of browser because all of the PCs get their updates at the same time. That user started facing this issue on last Friday. Before this everything was working fine for that user.

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet view might have been created as a 'Personal' and therefore, any data entered via the view are not visible to the others via Standard 'Public' view. I'd assume the view may have been created without sufficent right for public view creation.